# How to copy the data within the pointer into a float array using memcpy()?

Tags: arrays, c, copy

I wanted to copy what's within the `amount` pointer into the `Fquantity[]` array, but it shows me error "argument of type "float" is incompatible with parameter of type "void*"". How should I make it work? Thank you.

```
    char buffer[BSIZE]; 
    char d[] = "\t\n"; //delimeter
    char *fcode(0), *amount(0), *hos(0), *next; 
    char Fcode[BSIZE][100]; //store in array to do comparison
    float Fquantity[BSIZE]; //store in array to do accumulation
    float total;
    int ctr = 0, x = 1;

    fopen_s(&fptr, "Dist.txt", "r");
    while (fgets(buffer, BSIZE, fptr) != NULL) //split string in FILE and store into Fcode and Fquantity array
    {
        fcode = strtok_s(buffer, d, &next);
        printf("\ncode: %s\n", fcode);
        memcpy(Fcode[ctr], fcode, 5);

        amount = strtok_s(NULL, d, &next); 
        printf("amount: %.1f\n", atof(amount));
        memcpy(Fquantity[ctr], amount, 5); //Fquantity[ctr] shows the error
        
        hos = strtok_s(NULL, d, &next);
        printf("hospital: %s\n", hos);

        ctr++;
    }
    fclose(fptr);
```

Comment: *Where* do you get the error? Please [edit] your question to include both a [mre] (with comments on the lines where you get the errors) as well as the the full and complete build log.

Comment: As a hint: Please try to explain the call `memcpy(Fquantity[ctr], amount, 5)` to a [rubber duck](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging). Especially remember to mention the types of all involved arguments.

Comment: Take some time to think a little... You know you can convert a string into a `float` value with the `atof` function. Now you want to set a `float` value to the converted value of the string. Should you really use `memcpy` to copy the *string* into the `float` value? If you already have the converted value from `atof`, why not just *assign* it to the array element?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude do you mean by replace the ```memcpy()``` line with ```Fquantity[ctr] = atof(amount)```? If so, I've done it before and it shows me junk values. Please correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: That assignment is the correct way to do it. If you have "junk" values, then perhaps you check values in the array that haven't been initialized yet? Or maybe it's "garbage" in the input? How do you notice these "garbage" values? If it's easy to solve we can do it here, otherwise post it as a separate question (with the correct assignment).

Comment: What's wrong with `Fquantity[ctr] = atof(amount)`?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude it shows no error when I uses the assignment, however, it shows me junk values when I run the program.

Answer (score 0):

To use `memcpy` function, you have to give it the pointers of both buffers, But in `memcpy(Fquantity[ctr], amount, 5)` you gave it `Fquantity[ctr]` which is a value of a variable not address of it. To give it the address of `Fquantity[ctr]` just add and `&` before its name. So the answer is `memcpy(&Fquantity[ctr], amount, 5)`.

Comment: And that will lead to *undefined behavior* as you try to copy a five-character string into a four-byte `float` value.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Of course it may cause strange behavior but this is the answer of the question. I mean the error. In addition I don't know what he/she wants to do.

Comment: `memcpy(&Fquantity[ctr], amount, 5)` will copy 5 bytes, that's not good, and copying the characters from the string directly into the `float` array makes no sense either. You should dig more for a better answer.

Answer (score 0):

`memcpy` is not the right tool for your purpose: you must convert the textual representation of the numbers in the internal binary `float` format. You can use `strtod()` or `scanf()` for this.

Note that `char *fcode(0), *amount(0), *hos(0)` makes no sense in C.

Your system probably coerces you to use the so called *safer* string functions such as `fopen_s` and `strtok_s`, but it is useless to call `fopen_s` or `strtok_s` and not test their return values.

Here is a modified version using standard functions.

```
#ifdef _MSC_VER
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
#endif

#include <errno.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int read_data(void) {
    char buffer[256]; 
    char delimiters[] = "\t\n";
    char Fcode[BSIZE][100]; //store in array to do comparison
    float Fquantity[BSIZE]; //store in array to do accumulation
    char hos[100];
    int ctr = 0;

    if ((fptr = fopen("Dist.txt", "r")) == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "cannot open Dist.txt: %s\n", strerror(errno));
        return -1;
    }
    while (fgets(buffer, sizeof buffer, fptr) != NULL) {
        //split string in FILE and store into Fcode and Fquantity
        if (sscanf(buffer, "%99[^\t\n]%f%99[^\t\n]",
                   Fcode[ctr], &Fquantity[ctr], hos) == 3) {
            printf("code: %s\n", Fcode[ctr]);
            printf("amount: %.1f\n", Fquantity[ctr]);
            printf("hospital: %s\n", hos);
            ctr++;
        } else {
            printf("invalid entry: %s", buffer);
        }
    }
    fclose(fptr);
    return ctr;
}
```